# Record audio at 48Khz Flash

Tags: flash, audio-recording, sample-rate

I'm trying to record audio with a sample rate of 48Khz. I before tried using HTML5's AudioContext but this only outputted 41Khz. 
Is there a way (using Flash) to record audio at 48Khz?

Answer (score 1):

No.

In ActionScript 3 the max sample rate you can achieve is 44.1 kHz when using the Nellymoser Asao codec:

[image: relation between sample rate, mic.rate and bitrate with Nellymoser Asao]

You can also use the Speex codec but that has a fixed sampling rate of 16kHz.

Table from http://audior.ec/blog/audio-quality-and-bitrate-in-flash-as3-web-apps/

Answer (score 0):

No. In ActionScript 3 (Flash Player 9+) you can use [Microphone.rate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#rate) to set sampling frequency. `Acceptable values are 5, 8, 11, 22, and 44.` Actual frequencies differ a bit, so 44k means 44,100 Hz for example. These are the common values for sampling, so it should be fine for music, voice, etc, so you only need at least 48KHz for special use cases.